# coffescript(toggle function) with rails only works after page reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, toggle

```
jQuery ->
  $("#toggle_button").click ->
    $("#toggle_answer").toggle()
```

I have to refresh the page every time once to get the toggling to work as intended. If I do not refresh the page it does not work?

Is there a solution for this? Iv been trying to get it to work for about 3hr now. I tried so many other things such as:

```
$(document).ready() ->
  $("#toggle_button").click ->
    $("#toggle_answer").toggle()
```

and

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $("#toggle_button").click ->
    $("#toggle_answer").toggle()
```

I also tried not to use coffee script and just use javascript but I still get the same problem.

Is this a problem with how rails works? maybe the javascript is not loaded after clicking a link to another page? (I do not think this is happening, but I am out of ideas why it is not working)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is any ajax call involved? Remote link, form or something like that?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser ?

Comment: It seems like invalid HTML (like having the same id multiple times) may be a possible culprit...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with **#toggle_button** or **#toggle_answer** missing in your DOM when the event is fired or attached. You may try to use jQuery method `.on()` which will look for elements of a given selector and attach events to them when added to DOM:

```
$("#toggle_button").on "click" ->
    $("#toggle_answer").toggle()
```

`.on()` replace `.live()` and `.delegate()` functions in jQuery, you should read its doc: http://api.jquery.com/on/